# How to show all the host names of hosts within a specific OS in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Is there any command in Ansible to collect the hostnames of hosts with OS Debain?
The file hosts contains no groups!

So a simple command to see the hostnames of hosts containing Debain.

Comment: ansible -m setup hostname

Comment: I dont want to set the hostnames but only see the hostnames of managed nodes with linux distribution Debain

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-see-a-list-of-all-of-the-ansible-variables

Comment: Please check the link and let us know if that solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`setup`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html) module, which is implicitly called in any playbook via the `gather_facts` mechanism, contains [some output that you could use](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variables-discovered-from-systems-facts).
Look for example for the `ansible_distribution` fact, which should contain `Debian` on the hosts you are looking for.

If all you want is that list once, you could invoke the module directly, using the `ansible` command and `grep`:

`ansible all -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_distribution' | grep Debian`

If you want to use that information dynamically in a playbook, you could use this pattern:

```
---
 - hosts: all
   tasks:
     - name: Do something on Debian
       debug:
         msg: I'm a Debian host
       when: ansible_distribution == 'Debian'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add that if you want to target distribution and minimum version (often the case), you could do that with a dictionary. I often use this snippet:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    minimum_required_version:
      CentOS: 7
      Debian: 11
      Fedora: 31
      RHEL7: 7
      Ubuntu: 21.10

  - name: set boolean fact has_minimum_required_version
    set_fact:
      has_minimum_required_version: "{{ ansible_distribution_version is version(minimum_required_version[ansible_distribution], '>=') | bool }}"

  tasks:
  - name: run task when host has minimum version required
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_distribution }} {{ ansible_distribution_version }} >= {{ minimum_required_version[ansible_distribution] }}"
    when: has_minimum_required_version
```

You could also dynamically include a playbook fragment that targets specific distributions or versions like so:

```
- name: Include task list in play for specific distros
  include_tasks: "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yaml"
```

Which assumes you'd have Debian.yaml, Ubuntu.yaml, etc. defined for each distro you want to support.